# PhpSpec: How can I run only one test from a suite?

Tags: php, phpspec

I have a phpspec class like below and I only want to run a single spec from it.  I would like to run the  "it_should_do_something_easy" only.  Is this possible?

This is how I run this spec file:

```
$> phpspec run spec/Project/WorkerSpec.php
```

But now I only want to run a single spec like "it_should_do_something_easy".

```
<?php
namespace spec\Project;

use PhpSpec\ObjectBehavior;
use Prophecy\Argument;

class WorkerSpec
{
    public function it_should_do_something_easy()
    {
        $this->doSomethingEasy()->shouldReturn('Done!');
    }

    public function it_should_do_something_hard()
    { 
        $this->doSomethingHard()->shouldReturn('Too hard!');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Specify a line number the example method is defined on:

```sh
 phpspec run spec/Project/WorkerSpec.php:9
```